# HP Deskjet 3055a recognised on the network but not printing 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, printing, hp

I've been struggling to get my HP Deskjet 3055a to run and tried pretty much everything a windows-savvy but new to linux person can do. The printer has been automatically recognized and installed correctly on my laptop running the newest elementary OS distro.

On Ubuntu, I don't have the option to run the automatic installer, clicking on printers shows me the manual configuration page:

[image]
[image]

I installed the newest HPLIB (3.15.9) which supposedly supports the HP Deskjet 3055a printer and ran it normally, using sudo and using su. None of it helped. HPLIB is installed, the printer is located but no print job reaches the printer. The only thing that changed is that when installing with root privileges, the computer was able to receive status information, while it couldn't otherwise.

I'd like to note, that the printer is connected to the network using WiFi. Our system is set up this way: The printer is connected to a router/bridge (don't know which term is appropriate here), which is responsible for our WiFi. The router/bridge is connected to a LAN router which is receiving the data from and transmitting the data to the web. (We access the internet via the TV cable.) The computer which is unable to send print jobs is mainly connected to the TV-cable-router using LAN. But I also have a WiFi dongle plugged in and also tried to set up the printer while connected to the network via dongle.

The printer had a different IP when trying to connect using the dongle (192.168.1.107). The IP shown using the WiFi dongle exactly the one shown on the printer's display. Still doesn't work though. (While connected via cable the IP is 192.168.0.10)

Following the generic troubleshooting guide for HPLIB, I was able to ping the IP address. But when trying the following:

```
snmpwalk -Os -c public -v 1 ip.address.of.printer 1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.1.1.7.0
```

snmpwalk was unable to get a response (yes I replaced the placeholder with the IP). HPLIB documentation does not provide any info on how to fix the SNMP configuration, instead it reads:

> If you do not get this sort of response then there is a problem with
>   your snmp configuration. Ensure that the required dependencies for
>   snmp are installed and/or refer to your distro documentation.

As I only found some fancy server stuff, I'm stuck here. What can I do to fix this problem? Would an upgrade to the newest Ubuntu release instead of the LTS version fix the issue?

Edit: `access_log` http://pastebin.com/p0rmZpkW

Comment: I had the same problem. Delete the currently detected printer and run `sudo hp-setup` on a terminal and follow the installation steps.

Comment: @Harris Tried it, got following response: `Searching... (bus=net, timeout=5, ttl=4, search=(None) desc=0, method=slp)
error: Unable to communicate with device (code=12): hp:/net/Deskjet_3050A_J611_series?ip=192.168.0.10
error:  Unable to print to printer.  Please check device and try again. `

Comment: Ran `sudo hp-setup` whilst connected via the dongle. `Done.` I'm able to access the printer's webpage and can run a WebScan. Still unable to print a test page, though.

Comment: Update: connecting the printer via usb works flawlessly. but i need wireless support.

Comment: I don't think the samba version nor the Ubuntu version is the fault here. I think it is a networking issue; e.g. your computer is in the 191.168.0.x network and the printer is in 192.168.1.xx. If you can get everything in 192.168.1.xx, I think it can be done quite easily. Can you?

Comment: @chili555 I can access the printer and even conduct scans when connecting to the bridge using the dongle. Still, I'm unable to print.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you delete any previous configurations. Then set up the printer manually using the Internet Printing Protocol (ipp). I suggest you use the URI of:

```
ipp://192.168.1.107:631/lpr
```

Click 'Apply' and follow the process to select HP and then Deskjet 3055a. Save and print a test page.